# Is there a way to send my demo to someone without me having to download it?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I just completed my first CS:GO competitive match, and a friend of mine wants to watch my "demo". As my internet is relatively slow, I don't want to download it and upload it again.

Is there a way for me to send my demo to my friend without me having to download it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, there is a way!**

1. Click on the Watch button on main menu.

[image: Click Watch]

2. Click on the Your Matches button.

[image: Click on the Your Matches button]

3. Pick a match from the left-hand side of screen, and hit the "Copy Share Link" button on right top.

[image: Pick a match, and hit the copy share link button]

It'll copy the match link to your clipboard, which looks like this:

> steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_download_match%20CSGO-kYpP8-BDS3P-9EBqy-CzoGX-RQCmQ

Which you can send to your friend (through steam or other platforms, but some browsers might block that link).

Your friend will be able to download the demo as long as it is stored on CS:GO servers, which is about a week.

If the "Copy Share Link" button doesn't have a download button on its left, your friend will not be able to download it and will receive an error similar to this:

[image: The expired error]

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, there is a way...

And you don't even need to download it off CS:GO servers. All you need to have is previously downloaded it, and that it doesn't need to have not-yet-expired.

---

Your replays can be found in your installation folder, under `.../SteamApps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/replays`.

Although there is no plain-text correlation (that I could see) between the replay 'hash' and the name, all you need to do is find the correct replay file and send its `.dem` and `.dem.info` counterparts to your friend.

Comment: If you open the Demo UI (console: demoui) while watching the demo, if shows the name.

Comment: There is a spelling mistake "pain-text". But the edit suggestion only allows edits with more than 6 chars